# Function pointer casting

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

Hello guys I'm currently facing a pretty annoying problem:

I'm writing a system of callback manager that works by using function pointers, now given the fact that far now I've been assigned void function pointers to some other non-void function pointers, I've realized that it's not actually allowed in C.

At the moment I'm thinking about casting the void pointer so that matches the prototype function I have for my each callback, but I cannot understand how to **implement the casting**.

Would it be viable or should I adopt another solution?

Currently these are my callback containers and their typedefs:

```
typedef void modbus_read_t(unsigned int uid, unsigned int address, unsigned int count, char* response);
typedef void modbus_write_t(unsigned int uid, unsigned int address, unsigned int *data, char* response);

typedef void system_read_t(unsigned int uid, unsigned int var_number, unsigned int count, char* response);
typedef void system_write_t(unsigned int uid, unsigned int var_number, struttura_system *storage, char* response );

void (*M_callbacks_r[3]) (unsigned int uid, unsigned int address, unsigned int count, char* response);
void (*M_callbacks_w[2]) (unsigned int uid, unsigned int address, unsigned int *data, char* response);
void (*P_callbacks_r[2]) (unsigned int uid, unsigned int var_number, unsigned int count, char* response);
void (*P_callbacks_w[2]) (unsigned int uid, unsigned int var_number, struttura_system *storage, char* response );
```

This is the prototype of the function that registers the callback:

```
void registerCallback(int systemType,int operationType, void (callback)(void*));
```

What has to be done is to cast `void (callback)(void*)` to one of the typedefs above.

Comment: Please note that using empty parameters lists, as seen in the accepted answer, is an obsolescent feature, which means it could be removed from the language in the future. Obsolescent features should not be used, and are left in the language for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, casting should work. The C standard allows casting between function pointer types, the only thing you shouldn't do is call a function by a function pointer that has the wrong prototype, i.e. cast back to the correct prototype before the call, in order to avoid undefined behavior.

Let's start by simplifying your arrays a little, for readability sake:

```
modbus_read_t*  M_callbacks_r[2];
modbus_write_t* M_callbacks_w[2];
system_read_t*  P_callbacks_r[2];
system_write_t* P_callbacks_w[2];
```

I don't know why you `typedef`ed the function type instead of the function pointer type, but I'll go along with it.

Now `registerCallback` can be implemented as follows:

```
void registerCallback(int systemType,int operationType, void (*callback)()) {
  // .. determine array by system type and operation type
  M_callbacks_r[0] = (modbus_read_t*)callback;
}
```

The reason I deleted the parameter from the `callback` prototype, is that in standard C, an empty parameter list conveys no information about the expected parameters (as opposed to C++ where it explicitly means "no parameters"). That way callbacks can be registered without requiring a cast.

---

As you mentioned in the comments, you are building with `-Wstrict-prototypes -Werror`. So an empty parameter list will not work for you. You are thus restricted to defining `registerCallback` like this:

```
void registerCallback(int systemType,int operationType, void (*callback)(void))
```

Note the explicit `void` in the parameter list. You will need to cast the callback when passing it to `registerCallback` as well as casting it back inside the function itself.

```
registerCallback(type, op, (void(*)(void))func_cb);
```

---

Side note: The `_t` postfix is reserved on POSIX systems. To be portable, it may be best not to name your types with it.

Comment: M_callbacks_r[0] = (modbus_read_t*)modbus_read_t; 
shouldn't it be 
M_callbacks_r[0] = (modbus_read_t*)callback; ?

Comment: Also what other solution would you adopt without using typedefs?

Comment: @Cristian - I wouldn't work without typedefing something as difficult to type as a function pointer.

Comment: Avoiding pointer typedefs is a good rule in general for writing readable code.  With function typedefs there is the added benefit that you can use the typedef to declare matching functions.

Comment: @M.M - I never thought about using function typedefs that way. Food for thought, thank you.

Comment: I have an error, it tells me that: error: function declaration isn't a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
 void registerCallback(int systemType,int operationType, void (*callback)()) {

Comment: @Cristian - Seems you are building with `-Wstrict-prototypes`. So an empty parameter list is not allowed in your configuration. I'll add a relevant bit to the answer

Comment: Functions with empty parenthesis are objectively a bad suggestion as this is an obsolescent feature.

Comment: Also casts are a good thing, as they indicate to the reader that the pointers aren't compatible.

Comment: @2501 - A fair amount of legacy code uses them. I personally doubt they'll be removed in C2x, maybe in the revision following it. And as for casting, it's good so long as you aren't doing it just to silence the compiler.

Comment: That is why it is marked as obsolescent. New code is not legacy code. OP is writing new code. Yes casting is good, that was my argument, but your example avoids them.

Comment: @2501 - Casting is a subversion the type system. Now, sometimes they cannot be avoided, but code that overuses them will break when an erroneous change successfully passes a cast that was superfluously introduced before.

Comment: @StoryTeller The empty parameter list is a subversion (and prone to breakage in the future), to hide casts. What you're doing is equivalent to casting, except the casts are missing, where they should be.

Comment: @2501 - I'm not subverting anything. Implicit conversions are there for a reason. It's no more a subversion than not casting the return of `malloc`.

Comment: Except that void* is explicitly defined to be convertible between object pointers, whereas such usage of empty parameters lists is exploting a loophole in the language.

Comment: @2501 - We'll agree to disagree about how much of a flaw it is. The designers of C++ considered the conversion from `void*` a flaw in and of itself, and somehow sold it as more type safe with a similar argument to yours. I disagree with that as well.

Comment: I'm giving you a -1 for using an obsolescent feature where it isn't necessary.

Comment: @2501 - Whatever floats your boat